# Is IShellDispatch5 really available from Windows XP?

Tags: c++, com, windows-xp

From the document of [IShellDispatch5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774116.aspx), its Minimum supported client is XP.

I tested on a XPSP2(5.1.2600) with shell32.dll(6.0.2900.2180). With an already-got IShellDispatch4, the QueryInterface() cannot work (works on win7).

So, is IShellDispatch5 really available from Windows XP? Or is it a document error?

Comment: Since the interface's purpose is to add a method to initiate a Flip3D, which didn't exist until Vista, and since that method itself is flagged as requiring Vista, clearly this is indeed a documentation mistake.

Comment: Euro Micelli, thank you for your answer.

Comment: According to [this blog](http://mike-ward.net/blog/post/00337/using-c-to-interact-with-the-shell-gotcha): "Windows XP only supports the Shell32.IShellDispatch4 interface."

Comment: Looks like a documentation bug: it's only method [`IShellDispatch5.WindowSwitcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774117) is documented as available Vista+